# Playing short sound on touch

Tags: android, touch

I'm trying to get my game to play a short sound when a tile is pressed, Android Studio is telling me SoundPool is deprecated so can anyone tell me what I should be using instead? This is what my SoundPoolPlayer class looks like, and it currently causes my game to crash:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SoundPoolPlayer {
    private SoundPool mShortPlayer = null;
    private HashMap mSounds = new HashMap();

    public SoundPoolPlayer(Context pContext) {

        this.mShortPlayer = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        mSounds.put(R.raw.click, this.mShortPlayer.load(pContext, R.raw.click, 1));
    }

    public void playShortResource(int piResource) {
        int iSoundId = (Integer) mSounds.get(piResource);
        this.mShortPlayer.play(iSoundId, 0.99f, 0.99f, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    // Cleanup
    public void release() {
        // Cleanup
        this.mShortPlayer.release();
        this.mShortPlayer = null;
    }

}
```

I then play the sound using the following code in my game activity:

```
SoundPoolPlayer sound = new SoundPoolPlayer(getContext());
sound.playShortResource(R.raw.click);
sound.release();
```

Comment: Yea, use `SoundPool`, it's perfect for this scenario. The `SoundPool()` *constructor* is what is deprecated, instead use the `SoundPool.Builder` to construct a `SoundPool` instance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use MediaPlayer inside onTouchListener as follow:

```
  mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext,
                        Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.YOUR_FILE_NAME));
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not setup media player for ringtone");
                mPlayer = null;
                return;
            }
            mPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to play sound you can use Android MediaPlayer.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```